# Create parameter based jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a long jquery function and I want to separate it as an plugin.
Normally, most jquery plugin has a selector element as below.

```
  ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.myPlugin = function( options )
    {
       // codes goes here
    }
    })( jQuery, window, document );
```

and the usage is something like this.

```
 $('.element').myPlugin();
```

---

But in my case, the javascript function doesn't really need a selector element, it only expect a value(parameter).

```
e.g 
function coolMethods(Str){
     return Str + doSomething;
}
```

So, how can I use this as a plugin?

I would expect the usage is like this

```
myPlugin.coolMethods(Str) // and this should return a value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need any jquery functionality (the `$(selector).` part) and you want to call it like

```
myPlugin.CoolMethod("abc")
```

then you need a `namespace` rather than a plugin.

There's a number of ways to generate namespaces and scripts to help this, but essentially a namespace is an object that contains functions, the basic setup would be:

```js
var myPlugin = {};

myPlugin.CoolMethod = function(param1) {
  return param1 + param1;
};

// to use this:
console.log(myPlugin.CoolMethod("abc"))
```

Once you start using namespaces, you can then have private methods/variables within that namespace if needed and can easily add other methods / sub-namespaces.

Another common way to setup a namespace is something like:

```js
var myPlugin = myPlugin || {};

(function(myplugin, $) {

  // can also use $ within the namespace declaration
  myplugin.CoolMethod = function(param1) {
    return param1 + param1;
  };

})(myPlugin, jQuery);

// to use this:
console.log(myPlugin.CoolMethod("abc"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem! you can create your plugin in this case and use it on each element without any relation with it!
generally, is not necessary that your function uses JQuery elems.

example:

```
$.fn.NewFunc /*Your plugin function*/ = function(param1){
    console.log("Oh! It's ok!!");
    console.log(arguments);
};
```

Usage:

```
$.fn.NewFunc("Hello!");
```

or

```
$("").NewFunc("I Am An Argument!");
```

or even:

```
$("AnySelector").NewFunc("param1", "param2");
```

---

If you dont need selected elems by `selector`, you can use other way similar these (**this is not a plugin**):

```
$.NewFunc = function(p1, p2){/*do somethings*/};
```

and use it similar this:

```
$.NewFunc("param1", "param2");
```

Comment: Your welcome. Advantage of this way is the same thing I thought about your question. I thought that you have a big project with different scopes in it and you want access to your plugin function in all of them and that's why you don't want use variables (similar assigning your function to window object: `window.MyPlugins={plugin1:function(param){...}}`, but your goal is using JQuery instead of window.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var PLUGIN_NAME = 'myPlugin';

    function plugin(options) {    
         var opts = $.extend(true, {}, $[PLUGIN_NAME].defaults, options);
        _print(opts.name);
    }

    var _print = function (name) {
        console.log(name);
    };       

    $[PLUGIN_NAME] = function (options) {
        new plugin(options);
    };

    $[PLUGIN_NAME].defaults = {        
        name: 'John'        
    };
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Usage:

```
$.myPlugin({
    name: 'Suzy'
});
```

Or

```
$.myPlugin();
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/digitalify/pen/ejgaag)